# How to extract the git commit hash in a Bluemix deployment?

Tags: git, github, hash, ibm-cloud

I need to display the application version for a Bluemix deployment, and I thought that the commit hash from the Github repo/branch from where the Bluemix Toolchain/Pipeline is configured can be used for this.

I have tinkered in the Bluemix web console - DevOps Toolchain area and cannot find a way to extract this commit hash into an environment variable that my app can use.

Comment: What led you to decide on using the Git commit hash for versioning?  Generally a Git Tag on the commit is used for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `GIT_COMMIT` variable in a stage that uses GIT as input.

```
NEXT_GIT_COMMIT="${GIT_COMMIT}"
```

You can then use the value as you see fit (`cf set-env`, write to a file, in a `curl` request, etc)